# Javascript not drawing text on canvas properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

over here, I am trying to pass an argument through this function "launch", the argument is tntLoader. however, it passes successfully and the function executes including the timer (interval) runs perfectly fine, the problem is that it is not displaying the whole text on the canvas. It just displays a tiny line. Yes the canvas object is loaded properly, everything is defined in the html file fine and good. So it's supposed to be like this: `launch(tntLoader);`.

```
var surface;
var timer;
var counter = 0;

var tntLoader= {
canvas:"canvas",
speed:30,
x:0,
y:0,
textSize:16,
canvasElement:0, /* Do not modify this variable */
surface:0, /* Do not modify this variable */
font:"Arial",
color:"#00000",
text:"Sample Text",
type:"fill"
};

function launch(feg){
    counter=0;
    feg.canvasElement = document.querySelector(feg.canvas);
    feg.surface = feg.canvasElement.getContext("2d");
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){drawText(feg);},feg.speed);
}

function drawText(drawingObject){
    if(counter>drawingObject.text.length){
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
    drawingObject.surface.font=drawingObject.textSize+"px "+drawingObject.font;
    if(drawingObject.type=="fill"){
        drawingObject.surface.fillText(drawingObject.text.charAt(counter),drawingObject.x+30*counter,drawingObject.y);
        counter++;
    }else{
        drawingObject.surface.strokeText(drawingObject.text.charAt(counter),drawingObject.x+30*counter,drawingObject.y);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either compensate for baseline by adding to the y position, or set the baseline to for example top:

```
drawingObject.surface.textBaseline = 'top';
```

Text is always drawn from its baseline represented by the y position. This is the common way.

Here is an overview what the different baseline settings does to the text:

[image: Baseline overview]
<sup>[Image source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas)</sup>

The other way is to of course add the *ascend* part to your y position. Although in the specs it's currently not implemented in any browsers and therefor not possible to get this value in a stable way.

You would have to estimate it by using for example the font-height. This can result in varying position depending on the browser's text engine so if you need accurate placement of text then the first approach is better (for the time being).

```
fillText(text, x, y + textSize*0.8); // 80% is approx. ascent height
```